# I have an error setting up connection string in asp.net core using app JSON and dependency injection

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.1

I am new to Asp.Net Core. I am trying to set up my connection string as suggested on the Microsoft official tutorial blog page. 
in my appsettings.json I have pasted the following code.

```
"ConnectionStrings": 
     {
          "PersonDBContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=name;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
     }
```

and my `Startup.cs` file contains

```
     services.AddDbContext<PersonDBContext>(options =>
     options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PersonDBContext")));
```

I have inherited PersonDbContext from DbContext.

But upon compiling it throws the following error.

> Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Source      Suppression
>   State   Error CS0311  The type 'Gumshuda.DAL.PersonDBContext' cannot be
>   used    as type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method
>   'EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.AddDbContext
>   IServiceCollection, Action, ServiceLifetime, 
>       ServiceLifetime)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 
>       'Gumshuda.DAL.PersonDBContext' to     'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext'.  Gumshuda
>       C:\Users\nas\source\repos\Gumshuda\Gumshuda\Startup.cs    38
>       IntelliSense  Active

Please tell me how can I fix it and all about dependency injection.
My `PersonDbContext` is as follows

```
 public class PersonDBContext:DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: can you show implementation of PersonDBContext?

Comment: does your PersonDBContext extends DbContext?

Comment: @kriss I have updated my question with the implementation of PersonDbContext.Yup it does extend DbContext

Comment: That can’t be right, extending dbcontext forces you to have certain constructor

Comment: This contructor should be present: public PersonDBContext(DbContextOptions<PersonDBContext> options)
            : base(options)
        { }

Comment: I think I might have forgotten something. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The error pretty clearly indicates that your context is not inheriting from `DbContext`. However, you've posted the code for said context and it does in fact inherit from `DbContext`. Assuming that code is correct, then the only thing that makes sense is that it's not the *right* `DbContext`.

If you look closer at the error, you'll see it mentions that the context needs to inherit from `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext`. My guess is that you're your *actually* inheriting from `EntityFramework.DbContext`, i.e *not* EF Core, but EF6.

If that's the case, you cannot use `AddDbContext`, as that *only* works with Entity Framework Core, not EF6. It's possible that you accidentally referenced the Entity Framework NuGet when you meant to reference Entity Framework Core. Make sure your package reference is to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`, not `EntityFramework`.